# VHDL-2008 External Naming Compaction

Tags: vhdl, hdl, vivado, register-transfer-level

I am using external naming to instantiate the following code:

```
  snapshot_inst : entity work.snapshot
  port map (
    clk => clk_400,
    
    resampler0_data_i => << signal demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_i : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>,
    resampler1_data_i => << signal demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_i : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>,
    resampler2_data_i => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_i : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>,
    resampler0_data_q => << signal demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_q : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>,
    resampler1_data_q => << signal demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_q : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>,
    resampler2_data_q => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_q : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>,
    resampler0_valid  => << signal demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_valid : std_logic >>,
    resampler1_valid  => << signal demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_valid : std_logic >>,
    resampler2_valid  => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_timing_valid : std_logic >>,
    
    equalizer0_data_i => << signal demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_i : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    equalizer1_data_i => << signal demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_i : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    equalizer2_data_i => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_i : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    equalizer0_data_q => << signal demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_q : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    equalizer1_data_q => << signal demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_q : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    equalizer2_data_q => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_q : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    equalizer0_valid  => << signal demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_valid : std_logic >>,
    equalizer1_valid  => << signal demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_valid : std_logic >>,
    equalizer2_valid  => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_eq_valid : std_logic >>,
    
    phased0_data_i    => << signal demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_i : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    phased1_data_i    => << signal demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_i : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    phased2_data_i    => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_i : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    phased0_data_q    => << signal demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_q : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    phased1_data_q    => << signal demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_q : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    phased2_data_q    => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_q : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) >>,
    phased0_valid     => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_valid : std_logic >>,
    phased1_valid     => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_valid : std_logic >>,
    phased2_valid     => << signal demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext.ext_carrier_valid : std_logic >>,
    
    up_bus_in         => up_bus_in,
    up_bus_out        => up_bus_outs(9)
  );
```

As you can see, there is a lot of duplication in my referencing. Is there a way to do something like:

```
alias demod(x) is demod_deframe_gen(x).demod_inst.u_demod.ext -- Aliases a block, not a signal
```

That way I can shorten all of my external naming references?

Comment: `-- Aliases a block, not a signal`. What is this block you refer to? You don't display any declarations nor show design hierarchy. External names only refer to objects. In general you're not allowed to peer into design hierarchy other than through external names.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm wanting to alias a block inside an instantiated module. But I'd even be happy to alias an instantiated module. If that's not possible, is there any other way to shorten what I have?

Comment: 8.3 Selected names "An expanded name denotes a named entity declared immediately within a named construct if the prefix denotes a construct that is an entity declaration, an architecture body,..., and the suffix is ... a named entity whose declaration occurs immediately within that construct. This form of expanded name is only allowed within the construct itself, or if the prefix denotes an entity declaration and the expanded name occurs within an architecture body corresponding to the entity declaration."

Comment: in VHDL 2008, you can only use external names to signals, variables and constants. You cannot use an external name to get another type of item.

Comment: I also note you have tagged HDL and RTL. I am not aware of of vivado supporting external names for synthesis.

Comment: @user16145658 Please assume that I am not a VHDL expert and cannot yet interpret highly jargonized snippets of the LRM.

Comment: @Tricky I am synthesizing with 2022.1 and it works with external naming. I checked the schematic to verify. It will throw errors if it can't resolve an external name.

Comment: [External names are only of objects in -2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tZrr.jpg).

Comment: Ok yes - I admit I scanned too fast.

Comment: OTOH, VHDL is quite generous in what it allows aliases to be.   The point is that the OP is trying to use an alias to shorten the path that needs to be specified with the external name.

Comment: A pathname in an external name is even more flexible than a selected name (an expanded name) in an alias which requires visibility for each prefix name declaration. A [mcve] wouldn't be amiss here.

Answer (score 1):

What the OP is looking for is something to abstract and simplify the *external_pathname* of an external name.

If it were supported by VHDL, it could look something like the following, however, this fails both the OP's example in Xilinx and my test case (which requires a "." as the first path element).

```
alias demod0 is demod_deframe_gen(0).demod_inst.u_demod.ext ;
alias demod1 is demod_deframe_gen(1).demod_inst.u_demod.ext ;
alias demod2 is demod_deframe_gen(2).demod_inst.u_demod.ext ;

. . . 

  snapshot_inst : entity work.snapshot
  port map (
    clk => clk_400,
    
    resampler0_data_i => << signal demod0.ext_timing_i : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>,
    resampler1_data_i => << signal demod1.ext_timing_i : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>,
    resampler2_data_i => << signal demod2.ext_timing_i : slv16_array(1 downto 0) >>
```

There is no question that a capability of this sort is needed in the language.  I have added it to the following VHDL language issue:
https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues/115

Comment: If this does not work, it needs to be submitted as an issue to: https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues

There is a loosely related use case at: https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues/115

Comment: Great idea. Unfortunately it does not work for me in Vivado 2022.1. I get `ERROR: [Synth 8-10221] Failed to resolve external name ...`

Comment: Note the aliased demon0 - demod2 shown here denote expanded names which isn't encompassed in the simple names or labels found in the pathname_element syntax rule (8.7 External names).

Comment: @user16145658   Feel free to add something to the issue report if you like:   https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues/115.    Anyone is welcome to participate.   Perhaps read and comment on other items in the list if you like.